# Why this wrong IIFE function returns this

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with IIFE function and mistyped this. Paste the following into your console and press enter:

```
function A() {}("hello",6)
```

In the console, it prints `6`. Why is that?

Comment: JavaScript comma operator

Comment: I think you want `(function A() {})("hello",6)` for an IIFE otherwise this is the same as `function A() {};("hello",6)`

Comment: That code doesn't print anything to the console (unless you paste it into the console, ok)

Comment: The function isn't being invoked in the code though, and if you type it into the console, you see that it *does* print 6, for some reason. Sounds like a console oddity that has *something* to do with the comma operator, but I'm not sure exactly what

Comment: `Sounds like a console oddity` no, it's how the console works ... type "hello" in the console, it prints "hello", type 6 in the console, it prints 6 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The function doesn't return anything since it isn't executed.

---

A JavaScript interpreter is going to [parse this as **two statements**](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/d90ceab1b6edebe7ed15dde1b4daa295/552ff4c48f8a1644b7ca33735aa1f0c4e009e79c):

A **function declaration**

```
function A() {}
```

followed by an **expression statement**

```
("hello",6)
```

The expression statement consists of the [**grouping operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), containing the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which returns the result of the **right** operand, which is `6`.

As mentioned in the comments, if you want this to be interpreted as an IIFE, wrap the function definition (or the whole line) in parenthesis:

```
(function A() {})("hello",6)
// or
(function A() {}("hello",6))
```

Comment: `!function(){}(...)` is also an option

Comment: @Taplar, or `+`, `-`, `~` ... oh, I knew there was another one - as per below :p

Comment: Huh, interesting.  I thought `!` was a shortcut for the `()`, but I guess it's just forcing it to evaluate the expression or something?  New things!

Comment: @Taplar: Yes, `!` is the Boolean NOT operator.

Comment: So `A` is a function declaration, which isn't invokable, but putting parentheses after it doesn't throw an error (even though some linters might warn you that it will), it just results in the interpreter parsing the parentheses as a standalone expression (that may as well be on the next line) which gets evaluated and then discarded. (except that in the console, the final expression evaluated after you type in code gets printed, I think)